# I want to be able to do a multiple column lookup by only using the named range as reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is more for clarification it can't be done. It's something I've been thinking about for the last week, and feel it's now time to turn to the stack community.

Essentially I have a named range - Lets call it "Percentages". This named range is currently in the region of B3867:E4667 Thus having 801 rows.

This is how it is laid out (the top row is the headers, and x1 just represents any old number):

```
Title 1 , Title 2 , Number , Years

Data 1  , Name 1  , x1     , 0

Data 1  , Name 1  , x1     , 1

Data 1  , Name 1  , x1     , 2

....... , ......  , ...... , ...

Data 2  , Name 1  , x1     , 0

Data 2  , Name 1  , x1     , 1

Data 2  , Name 1  , x1     , 2

....... , ......  , ...... , ...

Data 1  , Name 2  , x1     , 0

Data 1  , Name 2 , x1     , 1

Data 1  , Name 2  , x1     , 2

....... , ......  , ...... , ...
```

The challenge is to obtain the number only knowing the named range name, Title 1, Title 2 and Years without vba.

Currently my thinking behind it is to use the index, indirect, match, address and offset function, but Every iteration I've tried so far comes nowhere near close. As far as I know, you essentially can't reference a column range within a named range.

Comment: Have you tried `SUMPRODUCT`? Seeing as you're looking to return numbers, it should work (though it'd rely on uniqueness of the data-name combo)

Comment: Something I've looked into, However, like you said, it would require the columns being a named range too. which unfortunately they aren't.

Comment: You should be able to reference columns in a named range using `INDEX` though - `INDEX(NamedRange,0,1)` for example should give you a reference to column 1 of your named range

Comment: Surely that is just giving reference to the header rather than the actual column itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more full (but untested!) answer based on my comments:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(Percentages,0,1)="Data 1")*(INDEX(Percentages,0,2)="Name 1")*(INDEX(Percentages,0,4)=0),INDEX(Percentages,0,3))
```

where the lookup values are based on the first row.

`INDEX` attempts to return the `i,j`-th entry of a matrix - so the first entry is at `1,1`. Using the value `0` returns the entire row or column instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, 1) for the answer, 2)for making me feel like a complete idiot. That'll be being stored away with regards to the i-j format and zero-ising(?) references the column or row

Comment: Never feel bad for not knowing something! 0 to reference entire rows/columns isn't particularly intuitive, but it's a useful thing once you start remembering it. Glad I could help!